# Microsoft Access grid/table control

Tags: ms-access, vba, report

Hello to the experts out there. I am creating a VBA MS Access report which needs to wrap data in few grids (tables) based on different categories and layouts.

Has anyone knows if there's a table (grid) control in MS Access, made available for creating reports?

The referred control is similar to what we have in MS WORD.

[image]

I searched around the web and through the MS Access API and documentation. 
I am not able to figure out if such a control is available, if not what are my options are in terms to drawing a table to the report. Perhaps calling WORD components from Access and then create a Word doc directly?

Answer (score 0):

You simply use the detail section as a row of the table. You can use control borders in tandem with the stacked layout to create a table-like visual report.

Ensure your control padding is 'None' and you are using a layout (stacked/tabular). You can find those in the 'Arrange' tab of the ribbon whilst in design view on your report.